# formsheet modal view controller won't dismiss in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I am trying to dismiss a formsheet modal view in iOS6. it works completely fine in iOS5 but fails in 6. (project uses ARC in both).

Here is the stack when it fails:

```
#0  0x0175a267 in objc_msgSend_stret ()
#1  0x006d55bd in -[UIView(Geometry) bounds] ()
#2  0x006cc707 in -[UIWindow _updateCurrentTintView] ()
#3  0x0075117b in -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] ()
#4  0x0097df44 in __91-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]_block_invoke_0236 ()
#5  0x0097d4eb in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] ()
#6  0x0077ba11 in -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] ()
#7  0x0077aecd in -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] ()
#8  0x0077bbdb in -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] ()
#9  0x00056a50 in -[HandDeviceToAssessorViewController dismiss:] at <directory of file>
```

The view controller is created by this:

```
+ (HandDeviceToAssessorViewController *)handDeviceToAssessorWithWellDoneView
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static HandDeviceToAssessorViewController *viewController = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^(void)
                  {
                      viewController = [[HandDeviceToAssessorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WellDoneHandDeviceToAssessorView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                  });

    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    return viewController;
}
```

and displayed with code:

```
HandDeviceToAssessorViewController *handBackModal = [HandDeviceToAssessorViewController handDeviceToAssessorWithWellDoneView];
    handBackModal.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:handBackModal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The view controller is dismissed by.

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewWillClose)])
    {
        [self.delegate viewWillClose];
    }

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void)
    {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewDidClose)])
        {
            [self.delegate viewDidClose];
            self.delegate = nil;
        }
    }];
}
```

I doubt/hope it's not a bug in iOS6. Any ideas as how to fix this?

Comment: I have found the problem; my own stupid error. Before the modal view is called by another UIViewController I am taking an image it's view and removing all it's subviews and sublayers. Incorrectly I was removing the sublayers before removing all the UIViews. Releasing the uiviews first has corrected this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the `dismissViewController` message to `self` instead of `self.presentingViewController`. It will be forwarded to the right View Controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sadly not. it was just self before and i was told to change it to self.presentingViewController as it was more correct. Sadly neither works though.